# What does Google do with our previous assets?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I want to know what Google does with our previous assets (eg. App Icons, Screenshots, Feature Graphics)? If I update any screenshot or icon on my Google Play Console then what happens with the previous one? Google stores these assets or deletes them? If Google stores them then how we can access them or from where we can delete those previous assets?

Comment: This question seems like it would be best answered by Google's own documentation e.g https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/